# It is possible to open an app after answering a call with the mobile screen blocked in CallKit?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

My problem is that I don't know how to call the opening of my app when the call from the callkit is answered with the screen locked, when the screen is unlocked my VOIP app works normally but when it's on the lock screen nothing works even my tasks start are invoked, my main goal is that when the user answers the call my app behaves the same as when it is on the unlocked screen

Comment: I'm also having same issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?